# mysql_query inside for loop gives mysql_fetch_assoc related error/warning

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to get the id's of the questions that are answered or asked by particular user and than im trying to use those id's and get questions where id is different from the id's retrieved from the first query.While trying to achieve this im getting an mysql_fetch_assoc() related error/warning and as a result my program crashes.

Following is the code from my DB_Functions.php file where im executing queries on database.

```
public function getQuestions($username){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT question_id FROM answered WHERE asked_by =  '$username' OR answered_by =  '$username'");
if($result){
$data = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
        $r=$row["question_id"]);}
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data); $i++){
            $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers EXCEPT WHERE question_id='$data[i]'") or die(mysql_error());
            return ($result2);
            }
    }else{
        return false;}
}
```

Following the code located in index.php where im trying to receive the result from DB_Functions.php

```
if($tag == 'getQuestions'){
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $getAllQuestions = $db->getQuestions($username);
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getAllQuestions)) { //I'm getting ERROR on this line
            $data[] = array(
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["id"] = $row["id"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["username"] = $row["username"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["question_id"] = $row["question_id"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["question"] = $row["question"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["tag1"] = $row["tag1"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["tag2"] = $row["tag2"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["tag3"] = $row["tag3"],
            $response["getAllQuestions"]["question_time"] = $row["question_time"]);}
            echo json_encode($data);
                    }
```

Below is the logcat message:

```
06-26 21:08:13.920: D/JSON(478): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android_php_1\index.php</b> on line <b>178</b><br />
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql_fetch_* expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674312/warning-mysql-fetch-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not support the `EXCEPT` keyword, so the query returns `null` to `$result2` because no result set was formed, which is why you're getting that error. Instead, you can actually consolidate those two queries into one like so:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    answers a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT question_id
        FROM answered
        WHERE ? IN (asked_by, answered_by)
    ) b ON a.question_id = b.question_id
WHERE 
    b.question_id IS NULL
```

In your `getQuestions()` function, you can replace the whole thing with:

```
public function getQuestions($username) {
    $filtered_username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $sql = "
        SELECT a.*
        FROM answers a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT question_id
            FROM answered
            WHERE '$filtered_username' IN (asked_by, answered_by)
        ) b ON a.question_id = b.question_id
        WHERE b.question_id IS NULL";

    return mysql_query($sql) ?: false;
}
```

Also note that your previous code was vulnerable to SQL injection. In my solution, I first passed the username variable through `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent that (not as good as prepared statements, but still better than nothing). ***NEVER*** pass user-input directly into a query.